# Is there an evidence-based study regarding the long-term psychological effects of spanking?

Tags: discipline

Any answers to this question I would hope would cite at least one reputable source; I'm really not looking for 40 opinions. As a nonspanker, I'm frequently surprised this is still in practice around the world--probably a majority. Most of my friends (including medical professionals and teachers) start out their defense/explanation "Yeah, but ..."

My concern is: everybody has a breaking point. Traumatic stress beyond a certain level damages the psyche, permanently. That point is different for each child, and once it's reached, you're child will never be the same. You don't know when you start spanking what the cut off is for causing emotional harm rather than "education." Does the evidence suggest my concerns are warranted?

I'm not trying to come across as judgmental, and I'm not looking for anecdotes. I'm wondering if there is bona fide long-term research on this subject. I'll even accept being soft if that's what the research suggests.

Comment: You can ask for literature on spanking, but (I'm sorry to say) this is more like a rant (please see the help section on [what not to ask](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). If you can edit to improve the question so that it is within guidelines, it can easily be flagged for reopening.

Comment: Current research suggests that some children aren't traumatized if it's not very much spanking and when fairly young,  but that it's still not effective parenting. Here's a sample of what you can find, citing several studies:  https://www.human.cornell.edu/pam/outreach/parenting/parents/upload/Spanking-Research-Brief.pdf

Comment: This should be closed as duplicate, [the answers here](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/are-there-any-reputable-studies-on-spanking) are probably the best available, and if there are better answers they should go on that question instead